# Android native sign-in Google webview usage warning email

Tags: android, google-signin

I have received the Google email warning about the usage of webview in one Oauth client for google sign-in, however, I have a single Android app that uses the Google Play Services auth library to provide Google sign-in.

The app requests an id token in setup, providing my backend server client id, configured in the Google Cloud Console as a web application as the [doc suggests](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id):

```
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(web-app-credential)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
```

So I have two oauth clients in google cloud console, Android and Web Aplication, passing web application to `requestIdToken` method above.
Everything works well. But the email links to a Google Blog post that suggests this is wrong:

Full post: https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html

> A "Web application" client type in use by an Android application is an example of mismatched use.

What should I do if the email says the affected client is the backend web-app-credential I use in my Android app? There seems nothing to be wrong with the setup as everything works fine.

If someone received the email and have the same use case as me please, give me some step to follow! Thanks!